# group by left(col, x) text column - possible to index?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, group-by

I'm looking for a possible index for the following:

```
select left(name,10), count(*)
from tab
group by left(name,10)
```

This is the table config:

```
create table tab(
id int(11),
name text,
primary key(id),
key name(name(10)))
```

The optimizer does not uses the index for the select. Any idea if that possible in MySQL?
In Oracle for example I can create index on functions, which is not supported in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=16ed5c3b84a029f8fa3f8760a807336e):

```
create table x 
(
  y varchar (25),
  z varchar (10) generated always as (left(y, 19)) stored, -- also virtual
  key (z) 
);
```

Or you could name the index as follows (see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8667f2ec0ea68ab3a0ad391b8ed925a2)):

```
CREATE INDEX x_z_ix ON x (z);
```

I find that giving explicit names to indexes is preferable - it gives more meaningful error messages.

Just because there is an index doesn't mean that the optimiser will actually **use it**! The table might be too small, too many nulls, skew in values &c.

I'm not exactly sure what your own create table syntax is actually doing - could you post the output of `show create table tab\G`.

Comment: FYI in MySQL 8.0.13 we can do one step further, create an index on an expression without needing to define a named virtual column. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html under "Functional Key Parts"

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT` has some drawbacks relative to `VARCHAR(...)`.  You have found one.

If `name` is a typical "name" of something, then it is probably never bigger than 100 characters, perhaps never bigger than 40.  I recommend using a suitable `VARCHAR` instead of `TEXT`, *whenever practical for your application*.

The "prefix" indexing is a kludge to let you have some flavor of indexing on `TEXT` columns.  However, as you are finding, it has some quirky limitations.  Yes there is a "generated column" workaround; that, too, is a kludge.